# Running a vim ex command within tmux corrupts pane

Tags: tmux, iterm2

I'm running into strange issue where running ack from within vim's ex mode corrupts my tmux pane. I'm using iTerm2.

E.g.

```
:!ack "foo bar baz"
```

Results in something like this:

[image]

where all the characters are replaced with gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure how this was causing the problem, but ignoring the `.sass-cache` directory in my project seems to prevent the corruption. I would not think that results from an ack search would be interpreted by my shell (zsh), but perhaps that is a possible cause?

I added the following to my `.ackrc`:

```
--ignore-dir=.sass-cache
```